# Supremum on measure space of a null set

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a measurable real
>   function. Let $\mu(A)=0$. Then $\text{ess} \sup (f)=-\infty$ and
>   $\text{ess} \inf (f)=+\infty$.

Define $\text{ess} \sup (f)=\inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid>c)=0\}$ and $\text{ess} \inf (f)=\sup\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid<c)=0\}$.

**My attempt**

By hypothesis, $\mu(E)=0, \forall E\in \mathcal{F}$. Since $f$ is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R})-$measurable, then $\mid f\mid$ is also measurable. Hence, $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}, \mid f \mid^{-1}\{(-\infty,c)\} \in \mathcal{F} $, and so, $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}, \mu(\mid f\mid<c)=0$. This means that $\text{ess} \inf=\sup\{c:c\in \mathbb{R}\}=+\infty$.
The result for the other case follows analogously.

Does this proof make sense to you?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: @Yanko You look to be experienced with this subject. Do you know any book where the properties of ess sup/ess inf are presented (without using 
 the notion of normed spaces)? There are a bunch of results that I have to show and I have only the above definition in hand. So I'm kinda insecure yet.